# Tar.gz with specific sizes but compressed files contains zero bytes

Tags: tar

Recently I took backup of certain folders by compressing them using tar.gz. I checked the file sizes and they looked like with specific sizes so I assumed that the files that got compressed must be in good condition.

```
total 724K
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4.0K May 15 17:07 crowdsourcing
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 609K Oct 16 06:02 crowdsourcing.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 5.7K Oct 16 06:02 cubam.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6.1K Oct 16 06:02 gaussian_mixture_models.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  234 Oct 16 06:02 github-repository.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  43K Oct 16 06:02 models-master.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  36K Oct 16 06:02 TensorFlow-Tutorials-master.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 5.1K Oct 16 06:02 What-Makes-An-Image-Memorable.tar.gz
```

However, when I downloaded backed up files from cloud and tried to unpack, they are all of zero bytes.

```
tar -tvf github-repository.tar.gz 
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu/ubuntu     0 2019-06-25 18:51 github-repository/online-crowsourcing-paper-implementation/
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu/ubuntu     0 2019-06-25 18:50 github-repository/.ipynb_checkpoints/
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu/ubuntu     0 2019-06-25 18:50 github-repository/
-rw-rw-r-- ubuntu/ubuntu     0 2019-10-07 10:34 github-repository/online-crowsourcing-paper-implementation/online-crowdsourcing-paper.ipynb
```

Somehow I think that if I can see different file sizes, there is the original data intact within tar but in corrupt format.

Can anyone tell me whether my assumption is correct or there is no other option to work on it?

Comment: Did you do a checksum of the compressed files while creating the archive and when downloading the archive on another machine and compare it?

Comment: How do you create the archives?

Comment: Did you notice that the ones listed by `tar -tvf` are directories, not files?

Comment: @Inian No. I didnt do checksum as I had very limited time to take backup and I had to take backup of entire machine.

Comment: @Kusalananda I created it from file manager (non-command line option)

Comment: @ChatterOne yes. But last one is .ipynb file which is zero bytes and just for an example I only chose a smaller archive. Other files contain relatively more files but showing all files as 0 bytes, but their file sizes differ. So I think my data must be there somewhere but due to corrupted archive, I cannot retrieve it.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you decompress? What does `tar -tvzf github-repository.tar.gz` show? What happens if you actually extract (`tar -xvzf github-repository.tar.gz `)?

Comment: @terdon when I extract from UI, all the files are of 0 bytes (from all the subdirectories) but the tar.gz files contain considerable size so I somehow believe that there must be data in it.

Comment: I don't know what UI you're using. Can you confirm that you get empty files if you run `tar -xvzf github-repository.tar.gz` from a terminal?

Comment: @terdon Yes. I ran above command from terminal. For UI, I tried to right click on tar.gz file in Ubuntu file manager and clicked on 'open with archive manager'.

Comment: I'm still not clear on if you ran `tar -xvzf` or just `-tvf` as you show in your question.  Can you confirm that you get empty files if you run `tar -xvzf github-repository.tar.gz`? I doubt it will change anything, `-tvf` should show the right sizes, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @terdon yes. I just did it and it gives my empty files.

Comment: Is there any way I can actually see raw content of tar.gz files?

Comment: What is the output of `tar tzf gaussian_mixture_models.tar.gz | gzip | wc -c` ? If it's close to 6000, then you probably have a file full of pathnames and tar metadata and nothing else.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Its output is 3640. Ohh, you mean to say all these tar files just contain metadata?

Comment: That might be the case. Can you go back to the original system and try creating tar files again? If that still creates zero-length files, we'll need to dig deeper. What program did you use to create the tar files, and by looking at the output of `df` on that system, what is the type of the filesystem where the original files are located?

Comment: That's the main problem. I had to upgrade my dual boot machine and before formatting everything, I had taken backup on One Drive. Since individual files were taking lot of time, I compressed them and stored. So, now I do not have original file system. :(